# Issue in executing DownloadToFIleParallelAsync method

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download azure blob into a local file using DownloadToFIleParallelAsync method to reduce the time required for download. But my program execution goes on to hold when that line executes. No any statements after that line is executing. Here is the code that I have written.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
    namespace demoAzure {     
    class Program     
    {         
    static void Main(string[] args)        
     {            
     var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();             Console.WriteLine("Downloading...");             ProcessBlob().GetAwaiter().GetResult();                         
    watch.Stop();            
    Console.WriteLine( "Execution Time: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");           
     Console.ReadLine();         
    }         

    private static async Task ProcessBlob()        
     {             
    string storageconnectionstring = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("storageconnectionstring");             CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;             
    CloudBlobContainer container = null;              
    string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);             string blobName = "large rfa_15mb.RFA";             
    string downloadFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, blobName);              
    if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageconnectionstring, out storageAccount))             {                
     try                
     {                     
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();                     container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("blobcontainer");                     await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();                      
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);                                          //await blob.DownloadToFileAsync(downloadFilePath, FileMode.Create); 
await blob.DownloadToFileParallelAsync(downloadFilePath, FileMode.Create, 2, 4 * 1024 * 1024);                     
// blob.DownloadToFile(downloadFilePath, FileMode.Create);                                         Console.WriteLine("completed");    
                 }                
     catch (Exception ex)                
     {                    
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 

     }             
    }            
     else            
     {                
     Console.WriteLine("No system environment variables are available. please set one");            
     }       
      }            
      } }
```

Comment: Hmm... sounds like an async await deadlock :/ If there is a synchronous version, you can use that since you are running it from a console app anyway and async doesn't really do any good there

Comment: There is not any synchronous version of parallel download. I want to increase the speed of download. I have tried using chunk downloads but it does not affects much